Only five outlets work
We took over ownership of a 1980s mobile home two years ago. Since than we've done repairs here and there as we go.
The first summer we lived here the electric went out in about 75% of the house. After many months and changing breakers etc. we found out it was a busted outlet which we replaced and the power worked correctly for about a year with no problems.
One night I had plugged in a phone charger and an outlet started smoking so I immediately shut the whole breaker box off. We replaced the outlet and turned the breaker back on. When we did there was no power in over half our house so we turned the power back off replaced with a different outlet but still nothing.
We replaced the breaker and about 54 outlets in the mobile home with no avail to the electric working again.
When we try to turn the breaker on it pops and won't actually fully go on. It is a double 20amp breaker.
When we replaced all the outlets we realized the ones under the windows were different and the hardware store said it was just what they used in the 80s and gave us regular duplex outlets to replace them with.
At this point we still only have five outlets that work in the house and three ceiling lights that work. The crazy issue is that not all of the working outlets are in the same room they are actually very random in the rooms.
Someone please help!

You have at least one dead short, hot touching/connected to ground. the breaker pops when turning on.  With the problems, one starting place will be the wires from the pole to meter(free from the power company).  Then meter to panel(electrician needed), then panel out to each circuit.  Back stabs and/or aluminum wire might be the problems.

Check Your breaker box. If it is a Federal Pacific brand IT MUST BE REPLACED!   That brand is known for breaker failures and  causing fires.  Don't take a chance , get it replaced ASAP.

If changing one outlet broke others, the problem is in the downstream connection from that box to the others. Check your wiring. Check your connections.
